# In what parts did facebook app use native code instead of react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm looking into creating an app using Reactive Native.

One of the reasons it's appealing to me is that it's already battle tested by apps like facebook.

With that said, facebook doesn't use react native for the whole app.

I can't help but wonder - in what parts did facebook use native code (java / kotlin / swift) instead of react native and for what reasons?

Comment: The only people who can answer this question are legally under NDA and can't.  But I can tell you that very, very little of it uses react native.  They didn't make RN because they thought it was a good solution (although some people drank the kool aid), they made it because they weren't able to hire enough mobile engineers (particularly Android).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what parts of Facebook are React Native or not, but we can assume a very large portion of each platform is not, especially looking at its need for native API's. React Native sounds so awesome, "Learn once, write anything". Unfortunately, as we have seen in many cross-platform solutions over the years, it is easier said than done. I think the way Google's Flutter is attempting a cross-platform solution is most likely the best yet, as it builds into native code for each platform without an abstraction layer.

Back to React Native:

Pros:

- If you are a JS guy you should have a natural leg up due to your
  underlying knowledge.
- Cost-Effective, one solution fits all.
- Simple UI (See below).
- Large active user base with plenty of development resources.

Cons:

- Immature and behind when updates come out to the various SDKS's (Or modules SDK's)
- Lack of security, open-source, less robust.
- Slightly slower, especially during thread initialization.
- Poor thread and memory management.
- Simple UI, Looking to do something more complex, it might be a challenge to achieve just what you want.
- Heavy usage of native code will still be expected.
- Non-native API and SDK support instead utilizes Native Modules.
- Blackhole debugging, longer debugging.
- Is Facebook, could always be abandoned.